# Cisco Mobility regarding JTAPI

Tags: cisco, jtapi, cisco-jtapi, cisco-axl

I'm developing an application using the Cisco JTAPI API. But one issue I'm facing is when the user enables mobility on his VoIP telephone. Then I'm unable to control the mobility call (the call forwarded to fx. the users mobile phone) through the JTAPI API as it's not tracked.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can control the call? Basically I just wanna hangup the mobility call in order to make the call return to the terminal so I can control it.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Once the call goes to mobile phone or any pstn gateway Cisco JTAPI cannot control it. JTAPI has fine grained control only for registered devices. I would suggest looking at Cayuga API from the Cisco Voice gateways to get similar controls on calls flowing mobile phones. These are part of the Integrated Service Routers (ISR) itself.